# How to configure EC2 security group to permit loopback via public IP address?

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-ec2

I have to run a program on an EC2 that reads the host's public IP address from config (which I don't appear to be able to easily change), and then connects to it, i.e. it's looping back to the instance via the public IP address.

I can't find out how to create a security group that can loopback to the the EC2 instance. My rules are:

outbound: 0.0.0.0/0 all tcp
inbound: [private IP/32, 127.0.0.1/32, public IP/32] all tcp 4440 (the port I need)

None of the inbound IPs work. I'm testing this by telnetting on the host to the public IP: `telnet x.x.x.x 4440`, and I'm never able to (where `x.x.x.x` is my public IP). I can do it by specifying `127.0.0.1` though, so the server I'm connecting to is online and bound correctly. I can also access the server through my browser. I just can't loopback. The connection hangs, which is why I think it's a security group issue.

How can I allow this program - which tries to connect to the public IP from the instance - to connect to the same instance by its public IP address?

Comment: Not sure why I've got a vote to close. The question is simple enough. If I have an EC2 with public IP 1.2.3.4, what security group rule do I need to set up so that when I run `telnet 1.2.3.4 4400` on that box (assuming there's a server listening on port 4440) it will connect?

Comment: something is definitely wrong. Either you are using the wrong public ip or your security group is not configured correctly.

Comment: @helloV Thanks just as long as I'm not completely misguided here. I'll keep digging to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a test (using ICMP rule) , you have to add a rule in the security group as you said. you should add it normally, and set the source to 1.2.3.4/32 (following your example). please note that I am using Elastic IP in my tests.

Comment: This worked for us.  Adding  the server's global IP worked (10.1.2.3/32). Adding the range that included the server's global IP (10.1.2.0/24) did not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html), it should also be possible to list that security group as its own source.  This would permit the loopback even if the IP address changes due to a stop/start.

> Another security group. This allows instances associated with the specified security group to access instances associated with this security group. This does not add rules from the source security group to this security group. You can specify one of the following security groups:
>
> - The current security group
> - A different security group for the same VPC
> - A different security group for a peer VPC in a VPC peering connection